VSE; Text strip disappears when a video strip starts
A text strip that was showing its text disappears once a video strip starts showing a video. What can be the fix for this?
This issue occurs when the strip is placed in some channels on VSE, but in some of another channels, the issue does not occur i.e. the text strip continues to show even after the video starts.
Ubuntu 22.04, Blender 4.3.1 ("Help -> Release Note" button jumps to this page](https://www.blender.org/download/releases/4-3/?utm_source=blender-4.3.1))

(In the gif, Text.032 is the text strip, MetaStrip 3960 is the video strip, in question. Text strip 516 continues to show (Its text is stripped in the gif but it's the white letter on the top-right you can see "Ano" "str") even after the video starts, makes me believe something is wrong with either the Text 032 strip / with the channel it is in / both / something else.)

It seems to work fine, when Metastrip arrivs, it hides Text0.32 as it is above it

@moonboots Well Text strip 516 continues to show even after the video arrives, so no.

it's an image with a transparent background, so it lets see the image beneath

The Video Sequencer works with tracks that allow you to overlays images or videos, the image or video at the top of the stack will hide the one that is on the track below and so on. If an image or video has an invisible backround, of course it will let you see the image or video beneath.
Here, everything seems to work as it supposed to: Test Trip 516 plays, it is a text image with invisible background, then Text.032 plays, it is a text image on grey blocks with invisible background as well, you can still see Text.032 even though it is placed under Test Trip 516, because Test Trip 516 has a transparent background. Then Metastrip 3960, which is a video, plays. As this video is opaque and it placed over Text.032, no reason to see Text.032 anymore.
If you still want to see Text.032 you need to put it on a track that will be above Metastrip 3960.

Thx. Turned out I was missing a very basic of channel Ref (v4.3:

higher channels are displayed in front of lower ones.

